# Enable script tags with different type? Changing type attribute is not enought

Tags: javascript, html, tags

is possbile to run code that previosly were of an ignored content type. Example:

```
<script type="jquery">alert('WORKING!')</script>
```

Of course this tag will be ignored and not i would like to enable it. I tried with this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('script[type=jquery]').attr('type','text/javascript');
});
```

But nothing happens :/

Thanks for help!

Comment: What do you expect to "happen"?  The document has finished loading by the time you change the type.

Comment: How can i get the content inside? How can we run it? eval()??

Comment: Sorry, but... What is your really needs? There may be many different solutions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it, but your only option is recreate new script tag and remove existing:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('script[type=jquery]').each(function(){
        $(this).after(this.outerHTML.replace('jquery','text/javascript')).remove();
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="jquery">alert('WORKING!')</script>
```

Comment: It's not true : `eval($(this).html())` will work too, but as [Luca Colonnello stated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943831/enable-script-tags-with-different-type-changing-type-attribute-is-not-enought#comment-49928108) this question is most likely an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)